# If the array is empty I don't want to show results in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have code like this

```
   <?php 

   global $DB; 
   $useridQry=''; 
  $login_id = $_SESSION['USER']->id; 

   if( $_SESSION['idnumber'] == 3 ) 
   { 

    } 
 elseif( $_SESSION['idnumber'] == 2 ) 
 { 
    $records=$DB->get_records_sql("select * from {user} where 
    maildigest=$login_id"); 
   print_r($records);
 if(empty($records) && count($records){
 { 
   $userIds=''; 
   foreach($records as $row) 
 { 
  $userIds="'".$row->id."'"; 
 } 
 //$useridQry = " and st.userid IN ($userIds)"; 
 } 
 } 
  else 
  { 
   $useridQry = " and st.userid = $login_id"; 
  }
```

so what happened is if is there any records it will show in table

```
print_r($records);
```

when I use print,

But if is there no data it showing empty array like this `Array ( )`

so when it showing empty array also it showing data in my tables..i don't want to show data if it is empty array..

can anyone help me how to do that,

thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post your full code (the bit before the ELSE IF). This will help us identify potential issues.

Comment: You have to get rid of the `print_r`, that's really just for debugging.

Comment: Is `get_records_sql`, Moodle?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php (the php.net docu is quit good, btw ;) )

Comment: yes its moodle..

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: I think get_records_sql returns an object, and an object is an object, empty or not.  Cast to an array... It's hard to say since we don't know what `get_records_sql` does.

Comment: ok..if you have idea how to rectify that can you please help me..

Comment: get_records_sql is just like fetch records from db

Comment: there is a problme with the code at the moment: `if(empty($records) && count($records)) ` <- this will be always false...either $record is an empty array xor it has countable elements. delboy1978uk has already  given the answer: 1. `print_r` is a debug function, don't use it to display content 2. if you want to execute something only when the array is not empty, put an `if (count(...))` XOR an `if (!empty(..))` around it

Comment: like how i have to use

Comment: @cypherabe can you please explain me clearly..

Comment: change the if statement back to what you had it as, it was fine

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree... You see in your code how you're referencing the the records result? `$row->id`, that tells us it's a StdClass.

Comment: no if i change it's not working...what happened is if i used print_r inside if if is there any data it showing records in print.if it there no data nothing is showing..but still it showing data in datatable..

Comment: @bc2946088 can you please tell me the solution

Comment: Please try the solution I gave.

Comment: i tried its not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this snippet: https://3v4l.org/CjTuv

```
   $x = [];
    print_r($x);
    if (count($x)) {
        echo 'yes';
    }
```

`print_r()` will always display output. It's usually just for debugging. If you don't want Array( ) displaying, either remove the `print_r` or move it inside your if statement.

Comment: because `print_r()` is **OUTSIDE** of your `count()` check! Move it the line below!

Comment: checking..give me 2 mins

Comment: if i keep the print inside count..if it there users data it showing..if not its not showing..but still i can able to see the data in my data table

Comment: He has an object, count will always display yes.  So there isn't anything wrong with your code, it's not applicable.  If you count an object, it will always answer yes, even if it contains nothing.

Comment: No, he has an array. Look at the output when print_r is passed an object: https://3v4l.org/eZula

Comment: `$row->id` is an object.

Comment: Your link is an stdclass object, did you link me to the wrong place?

Comment: He is expecting an array of objects, yes. when there aren't any results, he has an empty array.

Comment: They act differently, becuase an object isn't full nor empty, it's an object.  See here... https://3v4l.org/3nJd3

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(!empty($records) && count($records) > 0){ ...
```

instead of:

```
if(count($records)){
```

Comment: That wont help https://3v4l.org/CjTuv He just need to get rid of print_r

Comment: As I understand he is using print_r just for debug. Look at this: "i don't want to show data if it is empty array..".

Comment: @user200 Can you make var_dump ($records) instead of print_r? May be $records are not empty array, but null or something.

Answer (score -1):

How about checking, if the array is empty?

```
if (empty($playerlist)) {
     // list is empty.
}
```